Как ускорить matplotlib?
def mp(mes): 
    mes = f'${mes}$'
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    ax.set_axis_off()`введите сюда код`
    t = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, mes,
        horizontalalignment='center',
        verticalalignment='center',
        fontsize=20, color='black')
    ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    bbox = t.get_window_extent()
    fig.set_size_inches(bbox.width / 90, bbox.height / 60)  
    plt.savefig('example.png')
    return 'example.png'

Использую matplotlib для рендера LaTeX кода в изображения для отправки в тг бота на aiogram. Однако этот процесс занимает секунды 3-4, что в контексте моего бота очень долго. В идеале надо ускорить и, если это возможно и уместно, асихронизировать, чтобы эта функция не могла быть прервана. Как это сделать?

А с каким текстом он так долго выполняется? Со строкой 'test' у меня за 30 миллисекунд ваш код отрабатывает. Чем длиннее текст, тем дольше, но чтобы секунды... Покажите пример текста.

как правило, вот такие примеры r"\text{Округлите число } " + '1,1234567'+ r"\text{ до тысячных}"/// возможно это как-то связано с моим стареньким ноутом? Часто замечаю медленную работу по сравнению с другими. Сомневался поэтому решил спросить. А то вдруг на сервере будет медлить

Да опять же порядка 50мс. Может вообще не в этом коде тормоза? А, ну если старый ноут... Может там и SSD нет и сама запись в файл тормозит? )

Весьма вероятно. Спасибо огромное, значит, на сервере все будет хорошо. Постараюсь решить проблему.
